# fatal Exceptio: Unable to start activity

Tags: android, exception

I am getting this error while running android application

**05-25 23:58:44.251: E/AndroidRuntime(1128): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.tabsswipe/info.androidhive.tabsswipe.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #46: Error inflating class**

Here is XML Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:fillViewport="true">

  <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="#00aff0" >

        <!--  Header  Starts-->
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@layout/header_gradient" 
                android:paddingTop="5dip"
                android:paddingBottom="5dip">
                <!-- Logo Start-->
                <ImageView android:src="@drawable/logo"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"/>
                <!-- Logo Ends -->
        </LinearLayout>
        <!--  Header Ends -->  
        <!-- Footer Start -->
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/footer"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="90dip"
                android:background="@layout/footer_repeat"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- Footer Ends -->

        <!-- Login Form -->
        <LinearLayout
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:padding="10dip"
          android:layout_below="@id/header">
          <!--  Email Label -->
          <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@string/text_color"
                android:text="Email"/>
          <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
                android:id="@+id/edit_username"
                android:singleLine="true"/>
          <!--  Password Label -->
          <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@string/text_color"
                android:text="Password"/>
          <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:id="@+id/edit_password"
                android:password="true"/>
          <!-- Login button --> 
          <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_login"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:textColor="@string/text_color"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"                
                android:text="Login"/>
          <!-- Link to Registration Screen -->      
          <!--  <TextView android:id="@+id/link_to_register" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
                android:layout_marginBottom="40dip"
                android:text="New to EdgeAccounts? Register here"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="20dip"
                android:textColor="#0b84aa"/>-->

        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- Login Form Ends -->        

  </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

and here is java code

```
package info.androidhive.tabsswipe;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.Console;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Button GetServerData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        /*Click Listener for Login Button*/
        GetServerData.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                // WebServer Request URL
                String serverURL = "http://ott.edgeaccounts.com/Webservices/LoginService.php";

                // Use AsyncTask execute Method To Prevent ANR Problem
                new LongOperation().execute(serverURL);
            }
        });    


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        /*@Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            //View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    //false);
            //return rootView;
        }*/

    }
     private class LongOperation  extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        // Required initialization

            private final HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            private String Content;
            private String Error = null;
            private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            String data ="";
            EditText user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_username);
            EditText pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_password);
            //TextView output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
            /*PreExecute Method*/
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                // NOTE: You can call UI Element here.

                //Start Progress Dialog (Message)

                Dialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
                Dialog.show();

                try{
                    // Set Request parameter
                    data +="&" + URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8") + "="+user.getText() + "&" +URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "="+pass.getText() ;

                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 

            }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
            /************ Make Post Call To Web Server ***********/
            BufferedReader reader=null;

                 // Send data 
                try
                { 

                   // Defined URL  where to send data
                   URL url = new URL(urls[0]);

                  // Send POST data request

                  URLConnection conn = url.openConnection(); 
                  conn.setDoOutput(true); 
                  OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream()); 
                  wr.write( data ); 
                  wr.flush(); 

                  // Get the server response 

                  reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                  String line = null;

                    // Read Server Response
                    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                        {
                               // Append server response in string
                               sb.append(line + " ");
                        }

                    // Append Server Response To Content String 
                   Content = sb.toString();

                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    Error = ex.getMessage();
                }
                finally
                {
                    try
                    {

                        reader.close();
                    }

                    catch(Exception ex) {}
                }

            /*****************************************************/
            return null;
        }
        /*Called at the end*/
        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            Dialog.dismiss();

            if (Error != null) 
            {

                //output.setText(Error);

            } else 
            {

                // Show Response Json On Screen (activity)


             /****************** Start Parse Response JSON Data *************/

                String OutputData = "";
                JSONObject jsonResponse;
                try {

                    /****** Creates a new JSONObject with name/value mappings from the JSON string. ********/
                    jsonResponse = new JSONObject(Content);

                    /***** Returns the value mapped by name if it exists and is a JSONArray. ***/
                    /*******  Returns null otherwise.  *******/
                    JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("Android");

                    /*********** Process each JSON Node ************/

                    int lengthJsonArr = jsonMainNode.length();  

                    for(int i=0; i < lengthJsonArr; i++) 
                    {
                        /****** Get Object for each JSON node.***********/
                        JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);

                        /******* Fetch node values **********/
                        String email       = jsonChildNode.optString("email").toString();
                        String adminId     = jsonChildNode.optString("adminId").toString();

                        OutputData+="email   "+ email +"\nAdminId   "+adminId;



                   }
                /****************** End Parse Response JSON Data *************/    

                    //Show Parsed Output on screen (activity)
                   // output.setText(OutputData);
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailsPage.class);
                    myIntent.putExtra("data",OutputData);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                    ////////////////////////////////////////


                } catch (JSONException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
     }

}
```

Comment: Also your java code of the MainActicitiy. from the Error, Line 46 in your MainActivitiy has the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
android:textColor="@string/text_color"
```

`textColor` should either be an (A)RGB integer like `#12345678` or a reference to a `color` resource like `@color/text_color`. It cannot be a reference to a `string` resource.

Comment: Also, always post the full exception stacktrace, including the nested "caused by" exceptions.